# Can one 'introduce a movement'?

Tags: word-usage

If movement is meant as in a political movement can one say:

*To introduce a movement*

Or would another verb be more appropriate?

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative, or just checking the appropriateness of this one word? (By the way, it sounds perfectly fine to me)

Answer (score 1):

You can say that someone *[fomented](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/foment)* a movement:

> **foment**, *v.*: to encourage people to have angry feelings or to protest or fight

If that doesn't quite fit, you can find many synonyms for *foment* [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/foment):

> instigate, incite, provoke, agitate, excite, stir up, whip up, arouse,
>   inspire, encourage, urge, actuate, initiate, generate, cause, prompt,
>   start, bring about, kindle, spark off, trigger off, touch off, fan the
>   flames of

Answer (score 0):

You can say, **Instigate** *a movement*.

**Instigate** (verb) [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instigate)

> Bring about or initiate (an action or event)

Answer (score 0):

The verb used with "movement" is most often "start."

Examples:

> - ISIS started a movement to establish an Islamic state.
> - Jane started a movement to have Martin Luther King commemorated with a statue in front of the courthouse.
> - Americans recently started a new movement against fascism.

For an actual comparison of "start" verses "initiate" in frequency of usage, here is a [Google Ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22started%20a%20movement%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl).  You can click this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22started%20a%20movement%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=zrN9W-ygLIuTjgS6mJOwDw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1097&bih=637&dpr=1.75) for more examples.